# Double Commander starting after 30 seconds, why?

Tags: debian, debugging, application

On a previous installation of Debian, there was no problem. [Double Commander](https://doublecommander.com/) started immediately. The same on Linux Mint on another machine.

But, since I have a new installation of Debian, where the `doublecmd` starts after ~30 seconds.

Any way to find out why?

I tried to re-install the app, but no change.

---

```
lsof -p <pid>
```

https://pastebin.com/raw/1XJmQF3s

---

```
strace -t -f doublecmd 2> strace.txt
```

http://uloz.to/xkbY5JJt/strace-txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a context of **`cups`** connecting to localhost and after 30 seconds timing out.

Snip of only important part:

```
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 open("/home/vlastimil/.cups/client.conf", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 open("/etc/cups/client.conf", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f582a2a58d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 fstat(10, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0666, st_rdev=makedev(1, 9), ...}) = 0
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 11
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 setsockopt(11, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 setsockopt(11, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, [1], 4) = 0
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 setsockopt(11, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 fcntl(11, F_GETFL) = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 fcntl(11, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 connect(11, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(631), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 28) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 fcntl(11, F_SETFL, O_RDWR) = 0
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:03 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:04 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:04 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:04 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:04 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:05 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:05 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:05 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:05 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:06 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:06 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:06 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:06 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:07 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:07 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:07 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:07 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:08 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:08 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:08 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:08 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:09 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:09 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:09 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:09 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:10 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:10 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:10 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:10 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:11 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:11 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:11 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:11 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:12 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:12 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:12 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:12 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:13 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:13 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:13 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:13 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:14 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:14 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:14 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:14 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:15 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:15 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:15 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:15 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:16 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:16 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:16 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:16 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:17 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:17 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:17 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:17 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:18 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:18 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:18 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:18 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:19 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:19 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:19 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:19 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:20 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:20 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:20 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:20 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:21 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:21 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:21 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:21 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:22 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:22 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:22 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:22 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:23 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:23 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:23 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:23 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:24 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:24 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:24 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:24 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:25 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:25 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:25 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:25 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:26 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:26 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:26 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:26 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:27 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:27 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:27 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:27 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:28 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:28 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:28 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:28 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:29 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:29 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:29 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:29 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:30 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:30 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:30 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:30 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:31 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:31 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:31 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:31 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:32 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:32 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:32 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:32 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:33 poll([{fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, 250) = 0 (Timeout)
[pid 16247] 15:04:33 close(11)          = 0
```

The rest looks ok. Do you have somehow set-up cups? Can you try to disable it in `/home/vlastimil/.cups/client.conf`, probably by `Browsing Off` or `BrowseLocalProtocols none`? Or there will be some possibility to set it up using graphic interface probably ...